# Dart observable list that does not delete and reinsert all elements on change

Tags: dart, dart-webui

We have some code that has a custom web component to display each element in an observable list.  It seems that when an element is added to the list, the Web-UI infrastructure sees fit to remove all of the DOM nodes that represent elements in the list, and then re-add them along with the new element.

Not knowing much about the internal workings of the Dart-UI code, I would actually expect the addition of an element in the observable list to simply add one (or more) nodes to the DOM, without removing any of the existing nodes from the DOM.

Is it possible to achieve this sort of behavior?

Comment: More of a comment than an answer; this behaviour kind of makes sense since the item being inserted into List is not guaranteed to be placed at the end of the List, or there may be several changes made to the List, including deletes. From an optimization perspective, it seems like less overhead to just redraw the List.

Comment: I remember seeing mention on the Web UI mailing list that this full refresh on single list element change is a known problem and they hope to resolve this in the future.

Answer (score 1):

There is an open issue for this: https://github.com/dart-lang/web-ui/issues/431. John wrote

> fwiw, I'm working on a data-binding overhaul right now. The new
>   implementation includes stable lists by default.

so this should be fixed eventually.